# WPF data binding is not working for second usage

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I'm using `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging` for communication between classes.

From my ViewModel I'm asking for an object of type view to use it as the content of my DialogHost ( part of the MaterialDesign Framework ):

**ViewModel:**

```
 Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("dialogFormOpenStaple"));
```

-

```
private void DialogReceived(string msg, object param)
{
    if (msg == "dialogFormOpenStaple")
    {
        this.dialogContent = param;
        this.isDialogOpen = true;
     }

 }
```

**View**

```
private void NotificationMessageReceived(string msg)
{
    if (msg == "dialogFormOpenStaple")
    {
        object content = new dialogEditMode();
        Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage<object>(content, "dialogFormOpenStaple"));
    }

}
```

All this is working fine. In my XAML itself I got some button bindings to RelayCommands.

```
<UserControl x:Class="kati2._0.production.dialogEditMode"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:kati2._0.production"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
        >
   [...]
   <Button Margin="8 0 0 0" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" Foreground="#FF757476" IsDefault="True" Command="{Binding dialogOpenStapleNo}">No</Button>
   [...]
</UserControl>
```

Those RelayCommands are defined in my ViewModel. When I open die Dialog for the first time and click on the button it's working fine. If I try it a second time the dialog also opens up but the click event is not getting triggered.

Comment: Is the second dialog perhaps reusing the 1st dialog instance (still clinging to the 1st, original VM instance) while your program otherwise works with another/new 2nd VM instance, thus causing the apparent disconnect between VM commands and dialog?

Comment: Sure, thats possible but what is it caused by?

Comment: How should i know? I have not written nor seen your code. I wish as much as you to have superhuman mental powers which would allow me to see into your mind and into your computer and point you at the cause of the problem with a big neon sign. But unfortunately i have to disappoint you (and myself)... :-(  What i am trying to say: It is up to you to debug and troubleshoot your code thoroughly, trying to hone in on the cause of the issue...